# Re-applying to a company, years later

Tags: job-search, applications

2 years ago, I applied for a position in a big technology company, and managed to make it to the final round of interviews. Unfortunately I didn't end up making the cut, and indeed, I do believe that I could have done better.

Fast forward to today, I'm employed, I have experience, and I'm job hunting. I came across a posting I am interested in at the same company I applied to work for 2 years ago, but in a different country (in which I now live). As I go through the application process, I find out that all of my information from the initial application is still there!

So, my question is: how will my previous application/interview affect my current application and my chances to get the job? Can I use my previous interview experience to get an upper hand?

Comment: This is difficult to answer, as it likely depends a lot on the internal policies of the company you are applying to.

Comment: @DavidK if you can share anything from experience, all the while considering those factors, please do!

Comment: @concerned_user DavidK is correct. It's difficult to answer because based on their hiring practices they may be inclined to give you a closer look based on your previous interviews, however, it would be surprising. More company's than not will only look at your previous history with them if you've been hired and, unless the reason you got denied before was for something explicitly beyond the scope of them simply deciding on a more qualified candidate at the time, you'll go through the same process. Upside: It'll help your interviews by showing that you have real interest in the company.

Comment: I would have expected this question to actually be along the lines as _"Do I explicitly remind them I already applied? If yes, how?"_

Comment: @Lohoris apologies for not being clear, but indeed, this is implied in the "Can I use my previous..." part of the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no *absolute* answer I can give you, but I have been in a similar situation where I applied for a position in an organisation, was shortlisted and interviewed but didn't get the role.  A few years later another role came up with the organisation.  I applied again, and this time was successful.

I don't know if there were any policies in place where you work, but given you got to the final round then you placed VERY well in the recruitment process previously.  I feel this may actually be advantageous rather than a hindrance.

Lastly, you have nothing to lose by applying!  All they can say is no :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't ask the answer will always be no. I would see your previous history with the company as an advantage. Your experience has also increased over the intervening years. The fact that you want to try again with this company shows you are committed to working with them and putting yourself forward again shows you are tenacious in pursuit of your goal. What you may need to do is explain why you are now suitable to this role if it is different from the role you previously applied for, but the slate may be clean with whomever you are interviewing with and these questions may not arise - just be prepared if they do ask.